# Why I can't edit my post? Warning that I am trying to spam!

Tags: bug

I am trying to edit [my post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115141/4742). However, when I trying to submit the changes. I got this warning

[image]

Ok, this is polite enough and also ridiculous enough. How could my post becomes a spam?

If I delete "as far as", system will warn me that "body cannot cantain 'I know the'"

---

**update**

Workaround has been found in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261622/271637)

Comment: I am not posting this as an answer as I have not done the work needed to cite sources and my memory may be faulty: I believe that automatic spam filters are put in place *in the short term* when there is automated spamming taking place.  If these spam posts have the phrase "as far as" in common it may actually be reasonable to block this for a while, although only IMHO if the spam is originating from (presumably hacked) established accounts such as yours.  I shall try to look into this but my advice at the moment is to wait it out.

Comment: Some apparently related posts on [Meta.SE]: [(203204)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203204/158428),
[(261609)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261609/158428),
[(263724)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263724/158428),
[(268509)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268509/158428)

Comment: Hi, @Mr.Wizard, but it has been quite a while now, I still can't modify my post, and I tried to delete "as far as", the system will warn me other phrases

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think I found what cause the problem. Here is what I want to add http://pastebin.com/6FSujEi5 . If delete those sentence with Chinese characters, It can be updated. If you directly paste all the paragraph, the warning shows. What is wrong?

Comment: This is beyond my ability to correct.  I suggest you post on [Meta.SE] and see what attention you get.  If it goes nowhere shall contact the developers myself to see what they will say.

Comment: [Unable to post Chinese characters due to validation filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263724)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I did as you said. And got workaround : )